# VSCode intellisense with C++ headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have searched for this but I can't find anything. If it's dupe I will close my question without any problem. I have a c_cpp_properties.json configuration file in VSCODE

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5",
                "/usr/include/c++/5",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5",
                    "/usr/include/c++/5",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                    "/usr/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include/*",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 2
}
```

I'm developing in Ubuntu 16.04. The problem that I'm facing is that when I type in my .cpp files intellisense for headers are not working.

```
MyFooClass.h
#pragma once

#include <cstddef>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class MyFooClass
{
private:
    //My private fields

public:
    MyFooClass();
    virtual ~MyFooClass();
    bool MyFooFunction();
};
```

When I implement MyFooClass.cpp using

```
#include "MyFooClass.h"
```

Intellisense is not working for functions and data in .h It seems to me that this should be enabled in by default in my configuration but I dont know if I must add something new. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you are still interested or anyone stumbles across this thread using Google:

VSC has to two different engines for auto-completion.
1. The legacy "Tag Parser"
2. The IntelliSense engine

The latter is the default one at this point, "Tag Parser" is a fallback solution. As you assumed, both are configured in `c_cpp_properties.json`. The paths in `browse` are searched recursively and used by Tag Parser only, whereas the paths in `includePath` are NOT searched recursively and used by the IntelliSense engine.

Given that your header `MyFooClass.h` is not located directly at the root folder but in a subfolder `include`, you would have to add `"${workspaceRoot}/include"` to your `includePath` in order to have a working IntelliSense code completion.

Nowadays they have a better documentation on this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md

Comment: this is interesting but do you have any solution to the problem? I am used to put header files directly to the cpp files (not a library builder), i.e. in the same folder, so that the relative path should work fine. Do I need to add ALL subfolders into includePath now (despite using ** which should do recursive search but doesn't?)