# VSCode IntelliSense Cannot Find Header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cuda, intellisense

I add CUDA 10.2 examples into Visual Studio Code,

and follow [VSCode intellisense with C++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612460/vscode-intellisense-with-c-headers)

to edit settings.json.

However, IntelliSense still shows NVIDIA_CUDA-10.2_Samples/common/inc/helper_cuda.h not found.

Would you mind helping me with finding which part I miss?

Here is the screenshot of settings.json

[image]

Here is the screenshot of workspace hierarchy

[image]

Here is the screenshot of not found header

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add includePath in .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json file

For example

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        ],
        "defines": [
            ""
        ],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++11",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
    }
```

You may add any path which outside workspaceFolder separately as one more parameter for includePath tag

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Can you share the whole path of c_cpp_properties.json? I searched my local VS code installation path but cannot find c_cpp_properties.json. Or do you create the file by yourself?

Comment: There is a hidden folder under your workspace folder, which is {work-space-folder}/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json